# gtk glade need help

Tags: user-interface, gtk, glade

I am using glade to make an user interface.

i have successfully generated the glade file

Now i have to include this file in my C code.

I am using following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
GtkWidget *builder,*window,*button;
gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
builder=gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder,"shiv.glade",NULL);
window=GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"window1")) ;
button=GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"button1"));
g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));
gtk_widget_show(button);
gtk_widget_show(window);
gtk_main ();
return 0;
}
```

My UI is a simple window having a button without any callback function.

I am getting following errors on execution

```
GTK-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_show assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET(widget)' failed
```

Comment: This question belongs to StackOverflow. (And probably was already asked and answered on SO.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
GtkWidget *builder,*window,*button;
```

with:

```
GtkWidget *window,*button;
GtkBuilder *builder;
```

this should fix.

### Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void 
close_window ( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer window)
{
    printf("application close...\n");
    gtk_widget_destroy((GtkWidget*)window);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *button;
    GtkBuilder *builder; 

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    builder=gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder,"a.glade",NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"window1")) ;
    button = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"button1"));

    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked",G_CALLBACK (close_window),window);
    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));
    gtk_widget_show_all( window );
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

From [GTK3 reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/):
GtkBuilder — Build an interface from an XML UI definition;
GtkWidget — Base class for all widgets

Comment: after that I declared GObject *window,*button 
and remved the typecasts from gtk_builder_get_object
   that worked fine
kindly clear the difference between GtkWidget and GObject

Comment: @shivgarg I edited my answer with an example. I hope this helps.